# JMeter JDBC Sampler extract more than one column values

Tags: jmeter

I have a sql like the following in JDBC Sampler of JMeter

```
select id,code from table where .....
```

how do I extract the value of the two columns.

Comment: Did you find a workable solution?

Comment: Can explain more about what you trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to extract a value from the response?

If so, use the post-processor "regular expression extractor", attached to the JDBC request.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract all data, you can use he post processor "Save  Response to a file".

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file

What is good is that the output for each request is extracted to a separate file, very useful if you use the CSV data config with your request. You just specify the prefix for files.

The output will look like :

- result_save_1.plain
- result_save_11.plain
- result_save_13.plain
- result_save_15.plain
- result_save_17.plain
- ETC...

The Variable Name is very useful because it describe how you can reintegrate thoses files in JMeter using the variable name.

JMeter is a killer app!